# How do I round time to the nearest quarter hour using moment

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm trying to create an array of hours in a day with 15 minute intervals with moment to getting weather satellite image in utc time .

Example: `["2019_10_09_17_00", "2019_10_09_17_15", "2019_10_09_17_30"]`

The problem is the minutes are not fit `["2019_10_09_17_09", "2019_10_09_17_24", "2019_10_09_17_39"]`

l want to get minutes in fit `1700` not like `1709` or `1714` , because weather satellite image will not load if minutes are not fit ! .

Code

```
 // YYYY_M_DD_hh_mm

    const now = moment();

    const timeStops = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      now.add(15, 'minutes');
      timeStops.push(now.utcOffset(-1).format('YYYY_M_DD_HH_mm'));
    }

    console.log(timeStops);
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Well, its because you are taking the current time, then adding 15 minutes to it. You want to get the time, round it, *then* perform your for loop. The question you should instead be asking is "*How do I round time to the nearest quarter hour using moment*".

Comment: I will update questions title . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use moment to do this. Just generate all the minutes and hours, then combine into an array of dates.

```js
const pad = v => v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
const minutes = [0,15,30,45];
const hours = Array(24).fill(0).map((x,indx) => indx);
const hoursMinutes = hours.flatMap(h => minutes.map(m => [h,m].map(pad)));
const dates = hoursMinutes.map(([h,m]) => `2019_10_9_${h}_${m}`);
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: but i need to stay with updating date !

Comment: why looping is repeatedly ?